# Converting UITextField ( field.text) NSString * to char *?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I want to convert the `NSString* str` to `char* ch`, for using it as parameter in this function:
`str` is obtained from `UITextField's` text.

```
void CUserSession::Login (char *pUsername, char *pPassword)
```

Please help.

On using

```
ch = [str UTF8String];
```

//I am getting this **error.**

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'char *' with an rvalue of type 'const char *'
```

then On Using

```
ch = (const uint8_t *)[str UTF8String];
```

//I am getting this **error**.

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'char *' with an rvalue of type 'const uint8_t *' (aka 'const unsigned char *')
```

Comment: [Type Casting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) was useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace it

```
ch = [str UTF8String];
```

with

```
const char *ch = [str UTF8String];
```

or try with:

```
ch = (char *)[str UTF8String];
```

Comment: +1 @Midhun Type casting worked for me.. ch = (char *)[str UTF8String];
Please can you explain more about it. Why it worked on typecasting.

Comment: @HDdeveloper: this statement `[str UTF8String];` returns a `const char *` your `ch` is of type `char *` So you need to type cast it to char * using `(char *)[str UTF8String];`. It is similar to C type casting like: `int x = (int)7.6;`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try the obvious solution? Declare the pointer correctly:

```
const char *ch = [str UTF8String];
```

Comment: I tried that, but I want to pass parameter as char, which will be handled internal API's. Thanks for help. Type casting worked Midhun MP suggested. ch = (char *)[str UTF8String];
+1 for quick reply.. :)

Comment: @HDdeveloper The problem with that is that that will invoke undefined behavior if you try to modify the returned pointer.